# How can I access templated variables for another host in Ansible?

Tags: scope, ansible

**Background**

I am deploying to a system containing multiple hosts along with a monitoring host.  The monitoring host needs to use information about the other hosts to configure its monitoring checks.  However, variables defined as Jinja templates in host_vars/group_vars do not work when accessed through hostvars on the monitoring host.

**Example**

inventory.ini

```
my_host ansible_connection=local
monitoring_host ansible_connection=local
```

host_vars/my_host

```
---
my_var: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
```

playbook.yml

```
---
- hosts: my_host
  tasks:
    - debug: var=my_var

- hosts: monitoring_host
  tasks:
    - debug: var="hostvars['my_host']['my_var']"
```

The expectation is that the two debug task will output the same value, `"my_host"`.  In Ansible 1.7, the second debug task outputs `"{{ inventory_hostname }}"` (i.e. the template is not expanded).  In Ansible 1.8, the second debug task outputs `"monitoring_host"` (i.e. the template is expanded in the wrong context).

Is this a known bug?  Is there a good workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is buggy behaviour. Possible workaround:

```
---
- hosts: my_host
  tasks:
    - debug: var=my_var
    - set_fact: my_var="{{ my_var }}"  # Expanded in my_host context

- hosts: monitoring_host
  tasks:
    - debug: var="hostvars['my_host']['my_var']"
```

Comment: I figured something like this would work, but... hngggg